# Why FindInstance does not find this solution?

Tags: findinstance

Do you think `FindInstance` should have found this solution?

```
ClearAll[n, d, m, a];
n = 90; d = 3;
eq = n/d^m == a;
FindInstance[ eq, {m, a}, PositiveIntegers]
```

V 14 gives

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available
> to Solve. Try Reduce or FindInstance instead.

But we see that there is obvious solution:

```
eq /. {m -> 2, a -> 10}

(*True *)
```

I know I can find `m,a` in other ways, but wanted to know if there is a problem here and that `FindInstance` should have been able to find the solution. Btw, `Reduce` and `Solve` also can't find this solution.

Comment: Include constraints, e.g., `FindInstance[{eq, 0 < m < 100, 0 < a < 100}, {m, a}, PositiveIntegers, 5]`

Comment: Order matters, I guess: `FindInstance[eq, {a, m}, PositiveIntegers]`

Comment: @Goofy wow. This makes no sense at all!  But good find. Do you think this is a bug then? You can post this as answer if you want.

Comment: @BobHanlon thanks, Yes constraints helps. But I _think_ in this case it should not needed it?

Comment: Constraints are often useful and also work with `Solve` or `Reduce` for this problem.

Comment: Constraining either parameter is sufficient, `FindInstance[{eq, #}, {m, a}, PositiveIntegers, 5] &  /@ {0 < a < 100, 0 < m < 100, 0 < a < 100 && 0 < m < 100}`

Comment: @BobHanlon Not all constraints work, though: `0 < a < 1000 && 0 < m < 100` fails. @ Nasser, None of the `Integers` examples in the documentation have the variable of an equation in the exponent. These are harder to solve than polynomial equations, I think. Changing the order changes what is solved in terms of what (or affects how a Groebner basis is computed, at least for polynomial systems). Such a difference might affect the effectiveness of the algorithm(s). You could see what WRI says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We only have to constraint the range of parameter `a`

```
FindInstance[eq && a <= 50, {m, a}, PositiveIntegers, 5 ]
(*{{m -> 1, a -> 30}, {m -> 2, a -> 10}}*)
```